# How can I control which borders are affected by the insetting tool?

Tags: edit-mode

I am trying to modify geometry in a model I am working on. I want to inset one of my forms but only want the border at the top and not the sides as I want to extrude it inwards. I have tried with the boundary and individual options "on" but I can't get it. Am including an image. I must be close, but would need a hint as to how I can do it. Thank you.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Could you provide an image that shows the effect you are looking for? Your description is not sufficiently evocative.

Comment: I wish I could mate, but that image would be the final effect I am trying to achieve. If you reference the included image, I used an inset as shown. This resulted in 4 borders (the bottom one is hidden inside another mesh). So... is there a way to use inset and only have the top border and not the side or bottom borders when using inset? I want to extrude inwards the face highlighted in this image so as to create some sort of a trench with only the top border showing.

Comment: Perhaps you could sketch it, or find an example online?

Comment: Just added an image of what effect I want to achieve. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only control the boundary edge.
It's easier to

1. Select the top part
2. Extrude along normals
3. Check Offset Even

[image]

Comment: Perfect. Thanks very much!